# Bitmap 16bpp A1R5G5B5 to 32bpp

Tags: php, bitmap, rgb

I need to read the values ​​R, G and B image with a bit mask for 16bpp A1R5G5B5 in PHP, I know you have to understand Bitwise, but I'm not very good in this matter, so does anyone could show me how to do this?

Sorry for the English, is that I am Brazilian and I am using a translator.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which particular part about bitmasks don't you understand? Are you aware of PHP's bitwise operators?

Comment: A pixel in an image A1R5G5B5 equivalent to 2 bytes, I want to do is read the values ​​Red, Green and Blue pixels of using PHP, you know?

I know it's an alpha byte, 5 bytes of red, 5 bytes of green and 5 bytes of blue. But I need to know how to read those values​​, I know you can do using Bitwise, but do not know how, you know?

I need help!

Answer (score 1):

**A1R5G5B5 Bitmasks:**

```
       ARRR RRGG  GGGB BBBB

ALPHA: 1000 0000  0000 0000 - 0x8000
RED:   0111 1100  0000 0000 - 0x7c00
GREEN: 0000 0011  1110 0000 - 0x3e0
BLUE:  0000 0000  0001 1111 - 0x1f
```

Use the bitmask with the [bitwise AND operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to obtain the value:

```
$word  = /* two-byte (two octets) value per pixel */
$alpha = $word & 0x8000;
$red   = $word & 0x7c00;
...
```

Hope this helps. A PHP function that gives you the integer value for a binary number in PHP is [`bindec`](http://php.net/bindec), a function to convert an integer to a hexadecimal number is [`dechex`](http://php.net/dechex). Those functions are helpful to create a hexadecimal bitmask number from within PHP.

You can use as well a calculator to convert between binary, decimal and hexadecimal numbers, e.g. with a calculator like [gcalctool](http://live.gnome.org/Gcalctool).

Example code:

```
/**
 * unpack a binary string word of a
 * A1R5G5B5 color into an array of
 * RGBA integer 8bit values.
 * 
 * @param string $word
 * @return array('red' => int, 'green' => int, 'blue' => int, 'alpha' => int)
 */
function wordA1R5G5B5ToArrayRGBA($word)
{
    // unpack values from bit-fields
    list(, $dec) = unpack('n', $word);
    $blue  = ($dec & 0x1F);
    $green = ($dec & 0x3E0) >> 5;
    $red   = ($dec & 0x7C00) >> 10;
    $alpha = ($dec & 0x8000) >> 15;

    // map 5bit to 8bit (alpha: 1bit to 8bit)
    $blue = ($blue << 3) | ($blue * 0x7 / 0x1F);
    $green = ($green << 3) | ($green * 0x7 / 0x1F);
    $red = ($red << 3) | ($red * 0x7 / 0x1F);
    $alpha && $alpha = 0xFF;

    return compact('red', 'green', 'blue', 'alpha');
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a function that returns the RGB values ​​of these two bytes (2AF2) of a pixel of an image A1R5G5B5? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user1054127: You should find all information to do that on your own with the answer, so I leave it to you for some practice. If you run into a problem with writing that function, add what you have to your question and I can take a look.

Comment: Man I really do not know anything about Bitwise, please help me mount this function. :(

Comment: Man thank you i tryed alone and i win! jhajahjaha thank you so much.

Comment: Dude I built a function that worked yesterday with a color, but when I test with others do not work. Could check and tell me where I went wrong?  function read_rgb_a1r5g5b5($c) {
  $red = ($c & 0x7C00) >> 10;
  $green = ($c & 0x3E0) >> 4;
  $blue = ($c & 0x1F) << 4;
  return array(
   $red,
   $green,
   $blue
  );
 }

Comment: @Thainan Frota: I think there's something wrong how you shift the numbers. I added some example code, I did not compacted the shifts to have the variable to spread the missing part for the lower values across the fraction that the 5bits represent.